# How to enforce password complexity in Redhat?

Tags: linux, redhat, password

I googled and found a few links about it like these:   [Forcing Password Complexity in Red Hat](http://www.putorius.net/2011/03/forcing-password-complexity-in-red-hat.html)
[How to enforce password complexity on Linux](http://www.itworld.com/endpoint-security/275056/how-enforce-password-complexity-linux)

It says that we need to make changes in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file. I have set parameters for forcing password complexity and then tried to create a new user, but the rules set by me (like minimum number of characters and minimum number of uppercase letters and minimum number of numbers required) didn't prohibit me from creating the password which didn't follow these rules.

Please help me and let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try setting the password as the new user or as root? Password restrictions do not apply to the root user.

Comment: Yes was setting the password of a new user and not of a root user. First I logged in as a rot user and then applied the restrictions on the a new user and disabled his current password. Next when I tried to log in as this new user it notified me that I should change my password. So I was asked to enter my current password and I did. Then I was asked to enter my new password twice. This password that I entered was only 7 digits but I had set the condition for this password to have minimum of 8 digits but still i was able to create this new password. Please help.

Comment: You'll need to show us the changes you made to your PAM configuration. PAM is a complicated topic and something that even experienced system admins get wrong sometimes.

Comment: I set the following line in the system-auth file.
password   requisite   /lib/sequrity/$ISA/pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 ucredit=1 dcredit=1 ocredit=0 lcredit=0

Comment: Please edit it into the original question. You should probably show us the entire file as well, so that we can see how it interacts with the existing entries in your PAM stack. Thanks!

Comment: I think that link is not very clear, and it's not surprising that you may have been mislead. http://www.computerworld.com/article/2726217/endpoint-protection/how-to-enforce-password-complexity-on-linux.html is better IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

```
minlen=8 ucredit=1 dcredit=1 ocredit=0 lcredit=0
```

I'm guessing that you want your passwords to be at least 8 characters, contain at least 1 uppercase character and 1 digit. If so, that is NOT what you have configured.

For that you should use: `minlen=8 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1`.

Explanation: the minlen algorithm uses "credits" to determine the length value. Suppose you had a 6 character password. minlength would be no less than 6. Then, wihtout using any of the credit values, you would get 1 "credit" for using lowercase characters, 1 credit for using uppercase characters and so on.
Thus, a password of `Hello!` is 6 characters, +1 for using uppercase, +1 for using lower case, +1 for using special characters for a total minlen value of 9.

Specifying `ucredit=1 dcredit=1 ocredit=0 lcredit=0`, with the same password gives a length of 6, +1 for using uppercase, 0 for using lowercase and 0 for using special characters, for a length of 7. It does not FORCE you to use uppercase characters.

If you use a negative number for the credits, that requires you to have at least that many, and does NOT use credits.

So `minlength=8 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=0 lcredit=0` will then require the password to be at least 8 characters long, contain at least 1 uppercase character and 1 digit.
Thus a password of `helloboy` is 8 characters, but will fail. `Hellob0y` will pass. `He$$ob0y` will also pass.

Answer (score 2):

When you login via ssh `/etc.pam.d/sshd` policy file is used. This file includes `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, and you have to consider the contents of both files.

If you login via `/bin/login`, then the file `/etc/pam.d/login` is used therefore any changes to it will only affect `/bin/login`.

So you might need to make changes in both files i.e. `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/login`. Or change the one though which you want to force the password complexity.

Comment: Included files are *stacked* with the contents of the file. You have to treat the contents of the included file as being inline based on the position of the include. I've retracted my downvote and submitted an edit to your first paragraph.